# How do I verify if the url entered in my webview is valid and if not valid how do i redirect to some other url?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using an authenticated webview in my app. Currently when we enter the search term in the search box,it is added to the url (say http.cookies.com/something/**SEARCHTERM**/something) and the url is called in the webview which loads the url as follows:

```
 if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(URL)){


                if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL)){
                     mWebview.loadUrl(URL);
                }else{
                    mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                }
```

However, even if the url is invalid, it still loads the invalid url which shows up as "412- precondition set and hence page cannot be displayed".Is there a way I can detect if this search term or url is valid and display it in the webview , if valid) as the requested url , if not valid, i display some other webview like say google.com? 
[image]
Thanks!
justin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect 412 precondition failed errors in android webview url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009312/how-to-detect-412-precondition-failed-errors-in-android-webview-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Webview's [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to catch the error and do whatever you see convenient. Here is a sample:

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check the attached image, I have the function you mentioned in my code already.However it does not show the error as authentication error and displays the invalid url as precondition set as in my webview

Comment: `onReceivedError` is not called? Try to show a toast in there or log

Comment: I am using  @Override
     public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {
      Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Authentication Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
     }
and as i mentioned it is not an authentication issue,page loads as expected but within the page the search term is not valid and hence the whole url loads the precondition thing which means te search term is invalid, so was wondering is there a way to redirect to other url if the search term is invlid

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to check the valididty of the search term, I can post more code if need be

Comment: I rephreased my question with proper code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009312/how-to-detect-412-precondition-failed-errors-in-android-webview-url